# R make.unique start at 2 and leave the first occurence

Tags: r

I am trying to use the `make.unique` function but I need to append a suffix starting at 2 and avoiding the first occurence. This is similar to [the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659891/r-make-unique-starting-in-1) but I would like to keep the first occurence as is, for example :

`a b c d a b c d a b c d a b c d...`

would give

`a b c d a_2 b_2 c_2 d_2 a_3 b_3 c_3 d_3 a_4 b_4 c_4 d_4...`

Are there any simple ways to obtain this result?

---

EDIT

Sorry I should have mentioned that I was looking for a solution working with more generic vectors than the example above, for example already including digits at the end of strings or with a different order, something more like :

`vec <- c("a1", "b2", "c3", "b2", "d", "a1", "b2", "d", "e", "b1", "a2", "b3", "a2")`

In that case writing a `custom.make.unique` function is the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your custom `make.unique` function.

```
custom.make.unique <- function(v1, sep = '.') {
  vec <- as.numeric(ave(v1, v1, FUN = seq_along))
  inds <- vec > 1
  v1[inds] <- paste(v1[inds], vec[inds], sep = sep)
  v1
}

vec <- rep(letters[1:4], 4)
custom.make.unique(vec)

# [1] "a"   "b"   "c"   "d"   "a.2" "b.2" "c.2" "d.2" "a.3" "b.3" "c.3"
#[12] "d.3" "a.4" "b.4" "c.4" "d.4"

custom.make.unique(vec, sep = '_')
#[1] "a"   "b"   "c"   "d"   "a_2" "b_2" "c_2" "d_2" "a_3" "b_3" "c_3"
#[12] "d_3" "a_4" "b_4" "c_4" "d_4"
```

Answer (score 1):

`make.unique` is a internal function.  An option is to replace the digits (`\\d+`) at the end (`$`) of the string by adding 1 - using `str_replace_all`

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(v1, "(\\d+)$", function(x) as.numeric(x) + 1)
[1] "a"   "b"   "c"   "d"  
[5] "a_2" "b_2" "c_2" "d_2"
[9] "a_3" "b_3" "c_3" "d_3"
[13] "a_4" "b_4" "c_4" "d_4"
```

---

Or a similar option with `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("(\\d+)$", ~ as.numeric(x) + 1, v1)
#[1] "a"   "b"   "c"   "d"   "a_2" "b_2" "c_2" "d_2" "a_3" "b_3" "c_3" "d_3" "a_4" "b_4" "c_4" "d_4"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- make.unique(rep(letters[1:4], 4), sep="_")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```r
library(stringr)

v <-  c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d")

times <- (length(v) - 4) / 4

nums <- rep(seq(2, 1 + times), 4) %>% sort()

c(v[1:4], str_c(v[1:4], '_', nums))
#>  [1] "a"   "b"   "c"   "d"   "a_2" "b_2" "c_2" "d_2" "a_3" "b_3" "c_3" "d_3"
#> [13] "a_4" "b_4" "c_4" "d_4"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>